# Are there any book recommendation for identity, especially personal identity or metaphysics？

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, identity

I have studied philosophy on my own for a long time and gained overall impression on the history of philosophy. And I am interested in self-consciousness，particular in personal identity. Recently I get to learn metaphysics in analytical tradition.

Could someone give me any book recommendation on identity especially personal identity or metaphysics accessible to beginner？

Comment: You can start from SEP's [Personal Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/) as well as [Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/)

Comment: [Gallois, The Metaphysics of Identity](https://www.routledge.com/The-Metaphysics-of-Identity/Gallois/p/book/9780415843430) and [Noonan, Personal Identity](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Personal_Identity/6DaUb_tQRw8C?hl=en&gbpv=0) are fairly comprehensive and accessible. [Garrett, Personal Identity and Self-Consciousness](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Personal_Identity_and_Self_Consciousness/HMqEAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) is a little more demanding. See also references in [IEP, Personal Identity](https://iep.utm.edu/person-i/).

Comment: My Philosophy Cafe had a recent discussion about personal identity, bundle theory as the default theory used by physicalism, and the problems that bundle theory has, and whether they are resolvable.  This wasn't a single book, although the links reference books.  This discussion may be helpful for you:  https://www.meetup.com/Philosophy-Cafe-Central-Maryland/events/dkkmcsycclbxb/?comment_table_id=269687914&comment_table_name=reply